# Cannot update status of table specific instance because rollback is taking place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rollback

I have a table subscription with a column status. In my subscriptions controller I have a method `accept_player` that is supposed to update the `subscription.status` to `"confirmed!"`

```
  def accept_player
     @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subscription_id_accept_player])
     @subscription.status = "confirmed!"

     @subscription.save

     authorize @subscription
     redirect_to tournament_subscriptions_path(@subscription.tournament)
  end
```

unfortunately every time I try to trigger that method, a rollback seem to take place:

```
Started POST "/accept_player/39" for ::1 at 2015-07-08 22:01:21 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (12.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
/Users/davidgeismar/code/davidgeismar/tennis-match/app/controllers/subscriptions_controller.rb:141: warning: duplicated key at line 155 ignored: "CardType"
Processing by SubscriptionsController#accept_player as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aas8OPHBpvPwNbbmx/SVipsRM+eKo63nuVilMroxKcU9HRVonjSqEuH7aLY91gFi9PHMUsUqRqk7qhnv2m4L/A==", "subscription_id_accept_player"=>"39", "commit"=>"Confirmer ce Joueur", "subscription_id"=>"39"}
  User Load (13.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Subscription Load (11.6ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 39]]
   (5.7ms)  BEGIN
  Subscription Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subscriptions" WHERE ("subscriptions"."user_id" = 20 AND "subscriptions"."id" != 39 AND "subscriptions"."tournament_id" = 9) LIMIT 1
   (12.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  Tournament Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "tournaments".* FROM "tournaments" WHERE "tournaments"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/tournaments/9/subscriptions
Completed 302 Found in 246ms (ActiveRecord: 79.7ms)
```

Any ideas about what might be going wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
authorize @subscription
```

is probably causing the rollback. If you're in dev mode, just comment it out, `reload!`, and try to manually add a record and see if that's the cause.

Comment: ```authorize subscription``` is from the pundit gem. I also thought it could be causing the rollback. I did what you said but the rollback still takes place.